# best practice or prior art for javascript scheduling calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, libraries

This is a bit of a subjective question, and a red banner is warning me that it 'is likely to be closed', but I'm not sure of a better place to ask so here goes.

My application calls for a very lightweight display-only scheduling calendar.  Essentially an appointment book where you can see a few days or maybe a month at a time, and in each day you can see the various appointments, a-la google calendar.

The calendar needs to also have a reliable source for various holidays.

This does not seem like something I should be programming myself, since surely someone has already done the hard work, and I'm particually concerned about the holidays if I end up rolling my own.

Any suggestions for an existing product/library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice jQuery plugin.  Shows weeks at a time.

[http://www.webappers.com/2009/08/04/jquery-weekly-calendar-plugin-inspired-by-google-calendar](http://www.webappers.com/2009/08/04/jquery-weekly-calendar-plugin-inspired-by-google-calendar/)/

Comment: That is absolutely perfect...now what to do about a source for holidays?

Answer (score 2):

We embed a Google calender in one of our apps, it works for us, but I imagine a lot of developers would have branding issues or want better integration with there application.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/index.shtml

or

http://yellow5.us/projects/datechooser/

**EDIT**

http://www.ajaxrain.com/script?sId=6250
or
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml

Comment: Those appear to be simple 'date pickers'.  Not what I'm looking for, but thanks.

Comment: sorry , see edits, they do seem to have a full scheduler in javascript, what server side technology are you using? ASP.NET 4.0 has a lot of options for these type of consumer friendly applications.